# Nodejs Wait image will be downloaded

Tags: node.js, async-await

I can't understand why this function exit before image is downloaded and saved.
I need to wait image will be saved before exiting.

```
function downloadImagefromRemote(url_immagine, filename) {

        console.log('[2] Salvo l\'immagine remota in locale');

        const downloadFile = async (fileUrl, downloadFolder, filename) => {
            // Get the file name
            const fileName = path.basename(fileUrl);

            // The path of the downloaded file on our machine
            const localFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, downloadFolder, filename);
            try {
                const response = await axios({ // <----- here jump out
                    method: "GET",
                    url: fileUrl,
                    responseType: "stream",
                });
                await response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilePath));
                console.log("Successfully downloaded file!");
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }

        };

        const IMAGE_URL = 'https://www.kindacode.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/test.jpg';
        let rel_path = __dirname + '/../../public/images/';
        downloadFile(IMAGE_URL, rel_path, filename);
    }
```

Comment: `request` [which is deprecated and should not be used anyway](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) **doesn't return a promise** so it cannot be usefully `await`ed.

Comment: And that mix of `async/await` and `then` and callbacks is really hard to follow.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin , I've edited the function using axios, instead request.. But I've the same issue. I need to wait image is saved on storage before juming out. In the code I've commented where function going out

Comment: The pipe() function returns a stream, not a promise, and thus can not be awaited. You should instead create a new promise wrapping the pipe operation and resolving when the writable stream finish event fires, and await that.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that using

```
axios({...})
```

you need to specify

```
url: imgUrl
```

More generally speaking:

- avoid unnecessary nested functions
- clean your unused and unnecessary params

Here a functioning example:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const axios = require('axios')

async function downloadImage(imgUrl, saveRelPath, saveName) {
  const _path = path.resolve(__dirname, saveRelPath, saveName)
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(_path)

  const response = await axios({
    url: imgUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream',
  })

  response.data.pipe(writer)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', resolve)
    writer.on('error', reject)
  })
}

async function anotherFunction() {
  const IMG_URL = 'https://www.kindacode.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/test.jpg'
  const REL_PATH = '.'
  const NAME = 'test.jpg'

  console.log('Get and save image')

  await downloadImage(IMG_URL, REL_PATH, NAME)

  console.log('Image saving done, other stuff here')
}

anotherFunction()
```

EDIT: as response to

```
I can't understand why this function exit before image is downloaded and saved
```

the stream piping doesn't return a promise, so you can't await it.
You pipe a stream into a write stream that is an EventEmitter, so you should use a listener.

Comment: Alternatively, there's a utility function that wraps EventEmitters in a promise: `const {once}=require('events'); await once(stream, 'end');` it rejects on 'error' events.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that, it should work. for the pipeline() explaination, see this answer [Promise completed before file is written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961703/promise-completed-before-file-is-written/66962449#66962449). I promisified your flow to be able to resolve as soon as the stream process ends (note that i don t know about the other parts of your code, like if axios does not return a stream it will not work)

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream')
async function downloadImagefromRemote(url_immagine, filename) {

        console.log('[2] Salvo l\'immagine remota in locale');

        const downloadFile = (fileUrl, downloadFolder, filename) => {
          return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {

                // Get the file name
                const fileName = path.basename(fileUrl);

                // The path of the downloaded file on our machine
                const localFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, downloadFolder, filename);
                try {
                    const response = await axios({ // <----- here jump out
                        method: "GET",
                        url: fileUrl,
                        responseType: "stream",
                    });
                    pipeline(
                       response.data,
                       fs.createWriteStream(localFilePath),
                       e => {
                           if(e) reject(e)
                           else resolve("Successfully downloaded file!")
                       }
                   )  
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(Error(err))
                }
        })    

        };

        const IMAGE_URL = 'https://www.kindacode.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/test.jpg';
        let rel_path = __dirname + '/../../public/images/';

    try{
            const confirmDownload = await downloadFile(IMAGE_URL, rel_path, filename);
            console.log(confirmDownload)
    } catch(e) {
            console.log('catched err:', e)
    }
}
```